# How to do a xml based template for zend php

Tags: php, zend-framework, templates

I've seen how Magento generates their templates but I am not sure how to do it myself in my application.

Basically we want to be able to define something similar to:

```
<template>
  <section title="Recent Products">
    <snippet name="products" />
  </section>
</template>
```

Which in turn would be parsed.. somehow.. and render this code:

```
 <h1>Recent products</h1>
 <? include("Products"); ?>
```

(As an example...)

My main question is... is there anything written already that can do this? is there a term I can lookup online to get more information?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe an XML/XSL transform? ;)

Comment: Lookup DOMDocument and XSLT and work on what brady suggested

Comment: brady.. all done :).. I may be crazy.. but I think it didn't allow me to choose an answer because I was "new" but I might be wrong.

Comment: This are just comments, no answers. ;) You may ask in #zftalk @ freenode IRC